# How do I calculate the height of diagram created dynamically in gojs

Tags: javascript, gojs

How do I calculate the height of the diagram crated programmatically in gojs.

I am having  myDiagram.nodeTemplate  followed by myDiagram.groupTemplate

I am getting myDiagram.actualBounds as undefined.
myDiagram.outerBounds had height undefined.

I know once calculated i have to call:

```
var div = diagram.div;
div.style.width = 'I need to calculate this!!!';
diagram.requestUpdate();
```

But i dont know what width my diagram is.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `Diagram.documentBounds.width` most likely.

Have you seen: http://forum.nwoods.com/t/is-it-possible-to-have-dynamic-height-on-canvas/6450